# How to process and display the outer layer of html first before 'loading' the content?

Tags: php, buffer, flush, php-5.5

How can I ask PHP to process and display the outer layer of html first before 'loading' the content? For instance,

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Please wait, we are processing your request</p>
<?php include 'article.php';?>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to print this on the client browser first,

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Please wait, we are processing your request</p>

</body>
</html>
```

before showing whatever is included here,

```
<?php include 'article.php';?>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You need asyncronous loading, look into AJAX. The html you see in your browser has been output _after_ php has processed it

Comment: I want to avoid AJAX...

Comment: Is there a particular reasons for that?

Comment: I want to degrade my website gracefully when js is disabled.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, so you need AJAX to do this.

Comment: You would either need to just output the data with php and no delayed/lazy loading or you need to use javascript to load via ajax. The only other option is to echo out just your message and use a meta refresh to load another page with your included file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Jquery:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='article'>
   <p>Please wait, we are processing your request</p>
</div>
<script>
   $("#article").load("article.php");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The `.load` command gets the contents from whatever URL you provide, and sticks it in the named DOM element (`#article`).

Read all about it:
http://api.jquery.com/load/